# R - forcing each file's data into a different column during bulk upload

Tags: r

I am doing a bulk import with the following code

```
dat <- dir_ls(regexp = "*.csv") %>%
  map_df(read_csv2,
         col_types = cols(.default=col_character() ) )
```

Some files have simillar headings and *dat* has some columns with stacked data (when a couple of csv have the same headings).

To make things uniform, it would be convenient to force the data of each file to be launched in a different column (and to avoid columns with data from 2 or more different files, although they have same heading). Is it possible to achieve this with some addition to the previous code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first retrieve the files into a `list`

```
    mylist = lapply(dir_ls(regexp = "*.csv"), read_csv2,
             col_types = cols(.default=col_character() ))
```

Then `cbind` them together

```
as.data.frame(mylist)
```

This will ensure unique names.

Comment: I am getting a strange error when I try to run your first chunk of code. This happens with anyone of my testing folders when I set them as my WD:  Error: '38' does not exist in current working directory ....

Comment: Thank you.  Now it gives: object 'dir_ls(regexp = "*.csv")' not found

Comment: shame on me for missing the error too! It works! thank you